# Drain pipe under sink separated, how to fix?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, plumbing-fixture

What would be the best way of reattaching this pipe?

Found some of [this product](https://www.pioneer-adhesives.com/products/non-sag-epoxy) in the tool cabinet, would it be appropriate to use here?

[image] [image]

Comment: Is "that product" the same stuff that is all over the pipe joints? That is not how you attach pipes. Bring this picture of your pipe setup to your local plumbing/hardware/big box store and tell them you need to replace all of the pipes in the picture. You are missing a few slip nuts, I guess that's why what looks like silicone was used.

Comment: Home Depot is open in my state and we are locked down, everbuilt plastic 1-1/2” trap 3.84$  you would need a short piece and a nut from the sink. I got a complete kit not long ago with a couple of extra straight pipes to fix a sink for a friend I did not know what I needed but the kit had the trap and a few straight pieces maybe even a T but I think the whole thing was 15 and change it was chromed plastic. That was at Jerry’s home store , they are closer to me but don’t have a good web site like HD has.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the tail corroded away, unscrew the nut and take the short pice of pipe to a plumbing store or even a big box and replace both of them.  I would probably replace the  trap also it may break when you start moving it , a trap and the tail piece nuts seals and all will probably be under 20$ for plastic maybe 15$ .For a complete kit in a bag.

Comment: Hi Mr. Beal, thank you for the advice. How difficult would this replacement be for someone with no plumbing experience?  
  
Also, is there any temporary fix possible that would be worth the effort? We are quarantined right now and no shops are open.

Comment: Temporary fixes aren't going to be worth it. Are things really closed or pick-up only? You should be able to order online. I would try to call a plumber if you do not have experience, since it looks like the existing stuff will fall apart and wasn't done properly.

Comment: This is really simple the large nuts have a plastic or rubber seal that when tightened seals. I would not get flex pipe it looks like an accordion. Flex collects debris and doesn’t last compared to any other pipe. With plastic pipe it can be cut with a razor knife , sharp kitchen knife and hand tight is usually enough to seal up but an adjustable pair of pliers may be needed to disassemble.  With the drain in that bad of shape I doubt a temp fix will hold but I have found electrical tape, masking tape and packing tape all used as repairs with a pot to catch any drips but it will probably drip.